# Get variable value in IDL without using "print," sentence

Tags: debugging, variables, idl-programming-language

In IDL console I want another way in order to obtain variable value, for debug purpose. This is how I do now:

```
IDL> cvel=299.792458e6
IDL> print, cvel
 2.99792e+008
```

There is a easy and quick way to obtain cvel value in console? Like for example in the following (erroneous) command:

```
IDL> cvel
% Attempt to call undefined procedure/function: 'CVEL'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was added to IDL recently (at least by IDL 8.5, maybe earlier):

```
IDL> cvel=299.792458e6
IDL> cvel
   2.9979245e+08
```

Comment: I have 7.1.1 version. How I can know since wich version the new way works?

Comment: Looks like [8.3](https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/whats_new_8_3.html).